# i3 assign number to window and move to number

Tags: linux, hotkeys, tiling, i3

I am totally new to i3 and am coming from tilix. So far I love i3. In tilix I used to jump from windows to window using the $mod+numberOfWindow. But I can't find out how to

1. assign each window a number
2. focus windows by number.

With workspaces it automaticly assigns numbers and we can jump to them. How can I activate this for windows?

greetings!

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check in Edit 2

Answer (score 2):

In i3, we have workspaces displayed in i3bar displayed by numbers
You can jump to that workspace using
`$mod+number`

When we have multiple workspaces, then I use these bindings to move left and right workspaces

```
bindsym $mod+bracketleft workspace prev
bindsym $mod+bracketright workspace next
bindsym $mod+Left workspace prev
bindsym $mod+Right workspace next
```

In each workspace, we have different windows.
I personally prefer to use vim keybindings to jump to different windows

```
# change focus
bindsym $mod+h focus left
bindsym $mod+j focus down
bindsym $mod+k focus up
bindsym $mod+l focus right
```

For urgent workspace, use
`bindsym $mod+x [urgent=latest] focus`

**Edit 1**

I've found further options for assigning workspace names along with numbers.
There is also one rust script, which I found on github. It names the workspaces based on what application is opened in that workspace.
It can be found on github at [github.com/roosta/i3wsr](https://www.github.com/roosta/i3wsr)
Also, there's one issue [here](https://github.com/roosta/i3wsr/issues/22). Make sure
to check it out.

**Edit 2**

For naming windows, there are vim like marks, well documented in i3wm's
documentation.
Here's the [link](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#vim_like_marks)
I personally prefer, something like [github.com/svenstaro/wmfocus](https://github.com/svenstaro/wmfocus)
It works similar to chrome extension Vimium.

Comment: Thank you for the link to wmfocus, loving it!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your i3 config at ~/.config/i3/config

I don't really the concept of numbered windows. When we have multiple windows you can move around with focus.

```
bindsym $mod+Left   focus left
bindsym $mod+Down   focus down
bindsym $mod+Up     focus up
bindsym $mod+Right  focus right
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I am talking about windows and not workspaces. :/

Comment: please see the edit if that is what you wanted. @xddq